# Why does `ref` causes this example to *dereference* a field?

Tags: rust

I encountered the following (reduced) example:

```rust
enum Thing {
    A { value: f32 },
    B { value: f32 },
}


fn main() {

    let mut thing = Thing::A { value: 0. };
    let thing_mut_ref = &mut thing;


    if let Thing::A {value} = thing_mut_ref {
        *thing_mut_ref = Thing::B { value: value * 2.0};
    }   
    
   
}
```

The following does not compile because value is captured as a &mut f32, and thus does not support multiplying by 2.0.

What surprised me was that adding `ref` to the matched pattern suddenly makes it compile, i.e. captures by value (dereferences `value`):

```rust
enum Thing {
    A { value: f32 },
    B { value: f32 },
}


fn main() {

    let mut thing = Thing::A { value: 0. };
    let thing_mut_ref = &mut thing;


    if let Thing::A {ref value} = thing_mut_ref {
        *thing_mut_ref = Thing::B { value: value * 2.0};
    }   
}
```

I know `ref` for usually doing the opposite - stating that we *do not* want to capture by value. How does this explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not in fact dereference but convert the mutable reference into a shared one.
And as you can see from the [documentation of `Mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html) it is implemented for `&f32` and `f32` but not for `&mut f32`